# После запуска python скрипта сломалось что-то с раскодированием нажатия клавиш

Tags: python, кодировка, консоль, vi

В Vi не переключаются режимы. При открытии файла выглядит как на первом скрине[image: Вид при открытии нового файла].
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Второй скрин, это я нажал i для перехода в режим редактирования и начал вводить текст(большие буквы, это нажатия кнопок со стрелками)
На Backspase реагирует просто перемещая курсор влево по строке, иногда заменяет большие буквы, введённые нажатием стрелки, на маленькие.
В визуальном режиме работает нормально.

Заметил так же, что когда пытаюсь подключиться по ssh к серверу, на верный пароль отвечает, что пароль неправильный.
Может быть что то не так с кодировкой символов.
Перед тем как это началось, я запустил скрипт [switch-layout](https://github.com/yamnikov-oleg/switch-layout). После выключения скрипта, и даже перезапуска пк, проблема всё ещё осталась.

UPD: Сделал `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` смог подключиться к серверу. Там проверил, vi работает нормально. На моем пк остались те проблемы, что описаны выше.

**UPD**: помогло удаление vim.tiny и установка Vi.

Answer (score 0):

помогло удаление vim.tiny и установка Vi.
Скрипт меняющий раскладку видимо был не причем, т.к. с ним сейчас всё нормально работает.